# How to stop the video loop?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm playing multiple videos in a video tag. everything works fine.

However, I need the video to stop looping. At the moment, when all the videos played, the video starts again and it will loop through all the videos again.

To explain this issue, please run the following code:

```js
var videoSource = [
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4",
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
];


$('.playBtn').click(function(e) {
  var videoCount = videoSource.length;
  var video_index = 0;

  function onload() {
    videosToPlay = document.getElementById("videosToPlay");
    videosToPlay.addEventListener('ended', onVideoEnded, false);
    videosToPlay.src = videoSource[video_index];
    videosToPlay.play();
  }

  function onVideoEnded() {
    video_index++;
    
    if (video_index > videoCount - 1) video_index = 0;
    videosToPlay.src = videoSource[video_index];
    videosToPlay.play();
    //alert('all the videos played');
  }


  onload();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video src="" id="videosToPlay" width="320" height="240" controls style="background:black">
</video>

<button class="playBtn">
Play Videos
</button>
```

And this is a FIDDLE if required: http://jsfiddle.net/bnzqkpza/206/

Can someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need some code that makes it so when the video index is greater than the length of the array to stop the video. place that logic in your on Video ended

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you need to amend the `onVideoEnded()` function. At the moment it detects the index reaching the bounds of the `videoSource` array, and resets the index to 0. Instead, you need to simply invert the logic to only continue when not at the end of the array:

```
function onVideoEnded() {
  video_index++;
  if (video_index < videoCount) {      
    videosToPlay.src = videoSource[video_index];
    videosToPlay.play();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line `if (video_index > videoCount - 1) video_index = 0;`

When the `video_index` is greater then the video count (-1) you're resetting the `video_index` back to 0 aka the beginning.

You can change it to something like this

```
if (video_index > videoCount - 1){ 
    alert("all the videos played"); 
    return;
}
```

Comment: This fires the alert(); after end of each video: http://jsfiddle.net/bnzqkpza/207/

Comment: @DavidHope because that's not the code I have in my answer. Try http://jsfiddle.net/bnzqkpza/208/

Answer (score -1):

you are assigning video source repeatedly even after video count reached that why it made a loop . i just added those  statements else part.

**bug line**

```
 if (video_index > videoCount - 1){

             video_index = 0;
             videosToPlay.src="#";//

             }
videosToPlay.src = videoSource[video_index];//reasigning after ended which causes loop
        videosToPlay.play();
```

**corrected snippet:**

```js
var videoSource = [
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4",
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
];


$('.playBtn').click(function(e) {
  var videoCount = videoSource.length;
  var video_index = 0;

  function onload() {
    videosToPlay = document.getElementById("videosToPlay");
    videosToPlay.addEventListener('ended', onVideoEnded, true);
    videosToPlay.src = videoSource[video_index];
    videosToPlay.play();
  }

  function onVideoEnded() {
    video_index++;
    
       
    
    
    if (video_index > videoCount - 1){
    
         video_index = 0;
         videosToPlay.src="#";
         
         }
    else {
    videosToPlay.src = videoSource[video_index];
    videosToPlay.play();
    //alert('all the videos played');
     } 
  }


  onload();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video src="" id="videosToPlay" width="320" height="240" controls style="background:black" >
</video>

<button class="playBtn">
Play Videos
</button>
```

Comment: @David Hope check out my answer